# How do I force two circle nodes to touch on GraphViz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'd like to draw two circle nodes that touch each other. I tried to use `ranksep` for that, but that caused two problems:

- It can't be set to zero, so there's still some distance.
- Since `ranksep` is a global setting, and it affects all nodes, I have to add `minlen` to all the edges in the graph.
  Here's what I did:

```
digraph {
  graph [rankdir=LR, nodesep="1", ranksep="0.1"];
  a [shape=circle]
  b [shape=circle]
  a -> b [style=invis]

  x [shape=rect]
  x -> a [ minlen = 5]

  y [shape=rect]
  y -> a [ minlen = 5]
  
}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

Any idea how I can make them touch?

Comment: Q1: is this a one-time need or on-going?  Q2: is this the "real" graph or just a minimal example?

Comment: A1: ongoing.
A2: Just a minimal example. The real graph is bigger with about 5-6 circle pairs like this, and also other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

There are no simple ways to butt two nodes together.
Here are two not-so-simple techniques that get close:

1. create a stand-alone image of two circles as you want, then include that image in a single rectangular node:

```
graph ab {
  // build by hand/eyeball
  margin=0
  pad=.01
  node[shape=circle]
  a [pos="72,72"]
  b [pos="108,72"]
}
```

create the image file:
 `neato -Tpng -n2 mycircles.gv >mycircles.png`
(see https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords)
Then create the desired (complete) graph:

```
digraph ab {
  rankdir=LR
  node[shape=circle]
  b [label="" shape=rect image="mycircles.png" peripheries=0]
  X->b:nw
  Y->b:sw
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Or:

- Create the graph you want - except that the circle nodes are not touching.
- create an augmented input (with nodes and edges positioned) like so:
  ``dot -Tdot myfile.gv > myfile.dot`  (see https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/)
- edit the "myfile.dot" file - by hand or programmatically - changing the **pos** value for the second circle node
- run that edited file through this: `neato -n -Tpng myfile.dot >myfile.png
  Giving:
  [image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! option (1) will not work for me because I'd like to have different edges for each circle, so defining them as a single node won't do the trick.
Option (2) might do the trick, but since an edge can come out of the 2nd circle as well, I'll to change a lot of `pos` attributes.

Comment: I agree that both options are far from optimal, but note: edges for option 1 could connect to west side ports for "a" and east side ports for "b".  For option 2, use `neato -n` (not `neato -n2`) and neato will re-route all the edges, you just need to reposition the "b" nodes